# Prevent Double-Sided Clothing From Clipping Through Itself?

Tags: modeling, uv, rigging, cloth-simulation

I've given my character this sleeveless T-shirt and I'm happy with the model and texturing work, however I constantly run into the issue of it clipping through itself when animated with cloth simulation.

[image: Example]

As the inside is a darker blue, it shows up very obviously. (I cannot apply the solidify modifier afterwards because the design can be seen through the armhole.)

[image: UVs]
Here are the UVs so you can see clearer how my model works.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Such as a slider I can turn up to provide a small forcefield between polys of the same mesh? I've tried messing with a few of the settings to no avail. (For example, self collisions just caused the entire mesh to bunch up into a very strange shape.)

Thank you!